# Setting up github pages custom domain

Tags: html, css, frontend, subdomain, github-pages

I have a github pages repo in my organization and I am trying to add a www. sub domain to my .us custom domain on my github pages repo but I keep getting the error that says:

Both www.domain_name.us and its alternate name are improperly configured
Your site's DNS settings are using a custom subdomain, www.domain_name.us, that is not set up with a correct CNAME record. We recommend you change this to a CNAME record pointing to organization_name.github.io. For more information, see documentation (InvalidCNAMEError).

Can someone please help me any help would be apppreciated.

Comment: I've done this before, and got it to work with a couple tries. `domain.com` and `sub.domain.com`. These are 2 CNAMEs in 2 different repos. Did you also add the subdomain to your domain list in your registrar's dashboard?

Comment: @Eager to Learn I figured out the problem and corrected the problem in cloudflare and now github accepted the DNS check and my site is up but now when I go to my site I get the error Invalid SSL certificate error code 526. I also wanted to add that I am using a .us domain

Comment: in github, enforce https?